# ksh child process not ignoring SIGTERM

Tags: linux, ksh

My ksh version is ksh93-

```
=>rpm -qa | grep ksh 
ksh-20100621-3.fc13.i686
```

I have a simple script which is as below - #cat test_sigterm.sh -

```
#!/bin/ksh
trap 'echo "removing"' QUIT 
while read line
do
sleep 20
done
```

I am Executing the script From Terminal 1 - 
1. The ksh is started from /bin/ksh  as below :

```
# exec /bin/ksh 
2. The script is executed from this ksh- 
# ./test_sigterm.sh&
[1] 12136
```

and Sending a "SIGTERM" From Terminal 2 -

```
# ps -elf | grep ksh 
4 S root     12136 30437  0  84   4 -  1345 poll_s 13:09 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/ksh ./test_sigterm.sh
0 S root     18952 18643  0  80   0 -  1076 pipe_w 13:12 pts/5    00:00:00 grep ksh
4 S root     30437 30329  0  80   0 -  1368 poll_s 10:04 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/ksh

# kill -15 12136
```

I can see that my test_sigterm.sh is getting killed on receiving the "SIGTERM" in either case, when run in background (&) and foreground. 
But the ksh man pages say -
Signals.
       The INT and QUIT signals for an invoked command are ignored if the command is followed by & and the  monitor  option  is  not  active.
       Otherwise, signals have the values inherited by the shell from its parent (but see also the trap built-in command below).

Is it a know or default behaviour of ksh to NOT IGNORE SIGTERM? or is an issue with ksh child SIGTERM signal handling?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is normal behaviour.

While it says that signals are normally inherited by background processes, the
action of the TERM signal is determined by whether the shell is interactive or not.  (See the '-i' option in the ksh man page under Invocation.)

If you need the script to ignore SIGTERM, then you can add this line to it:

```
trap '' TERM
```